# Why jquery selector doesn't work for newly replaced tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Why `jquery` selector doesn't work for newly replaced tag.

I have a simple script, when the user clicks `submitResult button`, the server side returns a new div with id="content", and I used the jquery `replaceWith()` to replace the old one.

I noticed that after the `id="content"` element was replaced, the next time when I click submitResult, it doesn't send the data to server side. FYI, this submitResult id is inside the newly replaced element.

Can anyone tell me how to refresh the replace html tag, thus to let `$("#submitResult").click(xxx)` work again?

Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function handleData(data, status) {
        $("#content").replaceWith(data);
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submitResult").click(function() {
            var $result = $("#result").val();
            $.get("e?result=" + $result, handleData);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="resultbox">
                    <input id="result" type="text" value=""></input>
                    <input id="submitResult" type="button" value="Submit"></input>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- other content -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
$("#submitResult").click(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on("click", "#submitResult", function() {
```

Comment: The best delegate parent would be to use `#content` instead of `document`.

Comment: @zzzzBov is correct. The more specific the delegate parent, the less bubbling that needs to occur. Which was one of the main reasons `on()` was added and `live()` was deprecated, I believe

Comment: @zzzzBov: Isn't `#content` being replaced with `data`?

Comment: @Blender, derp! I should know better than to post comments after 1AM. You're right of course. My previous comment should say `'body'` rather than `'#content'`.

Comment: Great reply. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

`$("#submitResult")` returns the element present when you called the selector.

You need to use the event delegation syntax of `.on()` to attach the event handler to a fixed parent element and delegate it to the child:

```
$('body').on('click', '#submitResult', function() {
    ...
```

Comment: Great reply. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

use .on for dynamic elements in jQuery

jQuery events will work for only on the elements which loaded while page loading.

If you want to perform events on  elements which will come dynamically we need to use `.live` or `.on`

but `.live` is deprecated.

Comment: This is the way answer should be, clear short and applicable +1

Answer (score 0):

use `on` instead of `click`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitResult").on('click', function() {
        var $result = $("#result").val();
        $.get("e?result=" + $result, handleData);
    });
});
```

Comment: `live()` is deprecated. Use `on()`

Comment: `on` exists as of jQuery 1.7.

Comment: @NovalAgungPrayogo, [which is exactly when `on` was added](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: @NovalAgungPrayogo: *As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated*.

Comment: Good, now it doesn't delegate the event, please see other answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common senerio when we use ajax to return html content.
You bind an handler to old submit button when $(document).ready, but for the new returned button, nothing is bind to it. So you can explictly invoke the event binding js after ajax return, or just simply put   tag inside content div.

That can make sure the event binding run again after ajax return.